# How to change database view to Gallery?

Tags: notion-api

Using the notion API, I'm successfully able to create a database with a default Table view:

```
    await notion.databases.create({
        parent: { type: "page_id", page_id: response.id },
        is_inline: true,        
        title: [
            {
                type: "text",
                text: {
                    content: "Highlights",
                    link: null
                }
            }
        ],
        properties: {
            Name: {
                title: {}
            },
            ...
        }
    });
```

This Database shows up on notion using the Table view.

Is there a way to create a database with a Gallery view using the Notion API?

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of it, doesn't seem like there is a way currently with the Notion API version of 2022-06-28.